# remove all characters apart from number in pyspark

Tags: regex, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column called cola which has string data type example "100.z" or "102c"

How to I get rid of all letters or any characters apart from the numbers so cola becomes "100" or "102"

```
df.withColumn('cola', regexp_replace('cola', 'charsgohere', ''))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `[^0-9]` to match any non-digit. For example:

```
df.withColumn('cola_cleaned', F.regexp_replace('cola', '[^0-9]', ''))
```

Result:

```
+------+------------+
|  cola|cola_cleaned|
+------+------------+
| 100.z|         100|
|  102c|         102|
|x1022-|        1022|
+------+------------+
```